# How to construct a string which will pass if(variable)

Tags: javascript

I'm a jquery novice. I've boiled my code down to the simplest way to describe my problem. But I am having trouble wording it.

```
if(var1 && var2){
  // this works
}

searchMe = var1+" && "+var2;
if(searchMe){
  // this doesn't work
}

searchMe = "var1"+" && "+"var2";
if(searchMe){
  // still doesn't work
}
```

I would like to be able to construct that "`searchMe`" variable based on user input. Can someone tell me a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just do `var searchMe = var1 && var2;` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you can make use of `eval` function

```
if(eval(searchMe)){
  // this doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to do this without the dreaded `eval` (which really, you should *never* use) is to just evaluate as you go, and then end up with one variable at the end which is boolean.

```
var a = true;
var b = a && (false || true) && (1 < 2);

if (b)
    document.write('yes');
else
    document.write('no');

var c = b && false;
document.write(', ');

if (c)
    document.write('yes');
else
    document.write('no');
```

To relate it to your example

```
searchMe = var1 && var2;
if(searchMe){
  // this does work
}
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx - I won't post a long description as the blog and other Googleable pages can do that, but in short this para is quite a nice nutshell: "In the majority of cases, eval is used like a sledgehammer swatting a fly -- it gets the job done, but with too much power.  It's slow, it's unwieldy, and tends to magnify the damage when you make a mistake.  If you are considering using eval then there is probably a better way."